# Getting "missing core name in path" when trying to access Solr admin installed on Glassfish

Tags: solr, glassfish

I've installed Solr 3.1 on Glassfish, and that part passed smoothly, as when I visit`<host`>:`<port`>/solr, I get that "Welcome to Solr!" page, along with "Solr Admin" link.

Problems start when I try to opet admin panel, I get "HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path". I have no clue why is that happening. Previously, I've been testing that default Solr example (single core) at localhost, but using Jetty, shipped with Solr release in form of that start.jar.

I've set system property **solr.solr.home** to point to the folder where **solr.xml** and **conf** folder is located, and here's the content of mentioned solr.xml:

```
<solr persistent="false"
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="." />
  </cores>
</solr>
```

As you can see, just simple single core setup.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You wouldn't believe what was the problem... :) Part of the code that I've posted above, <cores> element to be more precise, was between comment tags. :) I've been installing Solr remotely, using SSH connection and did not pay attention to solr.xml when deploying it. I was examining it numerous times while I was searching for solution of this problem, but that comment tags just weren't eye-catching to me. :) Maybe because I used "cat" command for opening that file, instead of some syntax highlighting editor, like JOE. :)

Comment: could you please tell me where did you add this system property solr.solr.home to point to the folder where solr.xml and conf folder are? I am encountering similar issue but not able to change path of solr.xml to shared lib folder because i dont know how and where to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`<solr persistent="false"
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
    <core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />
  </cores>
</solr>`

and a directory structure of:

collection1 (containing dirs, conf and data)
solr.xml

is the proper way to do it.

Comment: That makes no difference. I've also tried multicore setup, for example:
<core name="core0" instanceDir="core0" />
<core name="core1" instanceDir="core1" />
... but that does not work neiter.