# Error 404: missing core name in path' in Solr

Tags: java, solr, tomcat7, http-status-code-400

I used:

```
//server.deleteByQuery( "*:*" );// CAUTION: deletes everything!
```

Query in my solr indexing program. Since then i am receiving the error whenever, I go to http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/

and press search with query string *:*

The error is:

> HTTP Status 400 - Missing solr core name in path
>
> type Status report
>
> message Missing solr core name in path
>
> description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Missing solr core name in path).
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.21

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path with solr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213123/http-error-404-missing-core-name-in-path-with-solr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you go to http://localhost:8080/solr/.
Can you check your `solr.xml` (in solr's root) for defined cores.
Also, you can check whether `solr home` is defined in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Check out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213123/http-error-404-missing-core-name-in-path-with-solr) for some similar and different solutions.
And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071112/getting-missing-core-name-in-path-when-trying-to-access-solr-admin-installed-o) too.