# Solr core not working

Tags: solr, lucene

I ave set up a new core in Solr and made the changes in the solr.xml to point to the new core.

And when I hit the below url

```
http://localhost/solr/my_new_core/select?q=*:*
```

Im able to get the below reponse

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">*:*</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

But when i try to index the data through the following command

```
http://localhost/solr/my_new_core/dataimport?command=full-import
```

Im getting

```
Error 400: Missing solr core name in path
```

How come its possible when the new core searcher is fine and why the data import is not working, the data import in working fine in my default core.

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you provide more details about the nature of the type of items you want to import.  Sometimes multi languages require specific configurations.
2. Can you provide your schema.xml or at least the parts mentioned in these other questions: [Getting "missing core name in path" when trying to access Solr admin installed on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071112/getting-missing-core-name-in-path-when-trying-to-access-solr-admin-installed-o) or this question - [HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path with solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213123/http-error-404-missing-core-name-in-path-with-solr)