# solr 3.4.2 HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path

Tags: solr, tomcat8

I'm trying to setup an old version of Solr for one of our drupal developers. Apparently only versions 1.x or 3.x will work with the current version of drupal.

I'm setting up solr 3.4.2 under tomcat.

I have solr living in /opt:

```
# ls -ld /opt/solr
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 May  6 12:48 /opt/solr -> apache-solr-3.6.2
```

And I have my cores located here:

```
# ls -ld /opt/solr/admin/cores
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 May  6 14:37 /opt/solr/admin/cores
```

Just one core so far, until I can get this working.

```
# ls -l /opt/solr/admin/cores/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root root 4096 May  6 14:08 collection1
```

I have this as my solr.xml file:

```
<solr persistent="false"
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores" defaultCoreName="collection1">
     <core name="collection1" instanceDir="collection1" />
   </cores>
</solr>
```

Which is located in these two places:

```
# ls -l /opt/solr/solr.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/solr.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 169 May  6 14:38 /opt/solr/solr.xml
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 169 May  6 14:38     /usr/local/tomcat/conf/Catalina/solr.xml
```

These are the contents of my /opt/solr directory

```
# ls -l  /opt/solr/
total 436
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 May  6 14:37 admin
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 176647 Dec 18  2012 CHANGES.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 May  6 12:48 client
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root   4096 Dec 18  2012 contrib
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 May  6 12:48 dist
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 May  6 12:48 docs
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   1274 May  6 13:28 elevate.xml
drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root   4096 May  6 12:48 example
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  81331 Dec 18  2012 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  20828 Dec 18  2012 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   5270 Dec 18  2012 README.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  55644 May  6 13:27 schema.xml
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  60884 May  6 13:27 solrconfig.xml
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root    169 May  6 14:38 solr.xml
```

Yet, when I bounce tomcat, this is the result that I get:

```
HTTP Status 404 - missing core name in path

type Status report

message missing core name in path

description The requested resource is not available.
```

Cany anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: whats do you see when you browse to http://localhost:8983/solr/ ...

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your search server uses a multi core setup.
In that case you need your core name as part of the URL.

e.g. instead of requesting

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=text
```

you have to request

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/yourCoreName/select/?q=text
```

please check whether solr home is defined in your WEB-INF/web.xml.

Check out this similar question for some similar and different solutions.

[HTTP ERROR: 404 missing core name in path with solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213123/http-error-404-missing-core-name-in-path-with-solr)

[Getting "missing core name in path" when trying to access Solr admin installed on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071112/getting-missing-core-name-in-path-when-trying-to-access-solr-admin-installed-o)